# Getting "Argument Invalid Exception Error" on using selenium for passing URL customized URL's to chrome driver

Tags: selenium-chromedriver

I have a text file which contains multiple random URL's.
Example: `https://5SnczRo6sk3hWl=10pfmNzxmNZ7f.geVxQ25XIQ%ic/%2O.nrw`

While sending it to chrome, for some urls I'm receiving mentioned error however for some it is working properly. (My aim is very simple: Send URL to browser ,check its output and then close the browser.)

PFB Code:

```
url = open ('URL_DB_new.txt','r')

url_rpt = url.read().split("\n")

for link in url_rpt:

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'D:\Software\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe')

print("link: ", link)

driver.get(link)

time.sleep(3)

driver.quit()
```

PFB Error:
[Selenium Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QvslX.png)

Any suggestion on how to handle this exception or remove it?